# How to match a left and right parenthesis and substitute a character for both in a regular expression in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to pattern match the following and substitute "c" for both a left and right parenthesis.

Example:
  string = "(a,b)"

So I want the string to come out like "ca,cb" after I call `string.sub(//,"c")` on it.  I've tried `string.sub(/[()]/,"c")`, but that only results in "ca,b)".  How do I pattern match the left AND right parenthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :001 > string = "(a,b)"
 => "(a,b)" 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :002 > string.gsub(/[()]/, "c")
 => "ca,bc"
```

Note the `gsub`: `sub` makes a single substitution; `gsub` ("global sub") substitutes as many as it can.

Answer (score 3):

For single char substitution try tr:

```
'(a,b)'.tr '()', 'c'
```

Comment: your single char substitution sentence forced me to do some research on `tr` on hola its a great helper ,I used it for blank submission but   I never knew it had some unique capabilities of substituting char by char.now m clear with the diff between `gsub` n `tr`

Answer (score 0):

If your expected output is really `"ca,cb"` rather than `"ca,bc"`, which is the result of the other answers given so far, then the following should do the trick:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > "(a,b)".tr('(', 'c').gsub(/(.)\)/, 'c\1')
=> "ca,cb"
```

You have not specified how to handle empty parenthesis or multiple levels, so those cases are not considered.